# Django Iterating Json Response In Template

Tags: python, json, django

I have this function which is making a request to an api with `get`. the response is coming back and expected and I am printing out each name of the objects returned to the terminal. But when I use the same for loop to print data in the template only the name of the last object is being rendered on the template page.

I was thinking maybe I am not executing my for loop properly but if that was true then why is my data outputting correctly in terminal.

In my view

```
def graphs(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        data = []
        r = requests.get('https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards')
        jsonList = r.json()
        cardData = {}
        for cards in jsonList:
            cardData['name'] = cards['name'] # Only last object name
            print(cards['name']) # Prints to termainl correct
        data.append(cardData)
        return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

This is in my template # I only get the last objects name

```
  {% for card in data %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ card.name }}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

When I move the data.append inside the for loop it appends the same name to the list for each time there is a card in the response.

```
for cards in jsonList:
            cardData['name'] = cards['name']
            print(cards['name'])
            data.append(cardData)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the dictionary and call `append()` *inside the loop*:

```
for cards in jsonList:
    cardData = {}
    cardData['name'] = cards['name'] 
    data.append(cardData)
```

Or, even shorter (and faster), with a *list comprehension*:

```
data = [{'name': cards['name']} for cards in jsonList]
```

Comment: Thank you this was the problem... Sigh. it is always something ridiculous. I will accept in 6 more minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes your simpler way. Please reach me this so in the future my life shall be easier. I can just create a new list comprehension for each field in the response like that? name | type | hit points etc? Where can I read how to handle complexed json like  "types": [
      "creature", "flyingthing", "mucles"
    ],

Comment: @wuno you can read more about list comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). If there are more keys you want to handle, simply do, e.g: `data = [{'name': cards['name'], "type": cards["type"]} for cards in jsonList]`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you declared

```
cardData = {}
```

outside your loop and the same instance is being written over and the same dictionary is being pushed onto the array. On the last iteration the entire list has the last name.

Move that declaration inside the loop. Or better still, just append each card onto the list.
Your indentation is wrong too. You only ever put the last instance on the results list. Do this:

```
for cards in jsonList: 
    data.append(cards)
```